# Validator Exception Spring Integration: returning an error message in validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Does anybody has an idea about how I can return an error message. I am trying to return an specific xml error message in my validator. This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        try {
            ValidationClassUtil.validateDocument(new String((byte[]) target), xmlVersionEnum);
            (//should the error be returned here when I send an invalid xml file over http?)
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            errors.reject(errorCode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what `Validator` contract is for. You cannot return from it anything. You can use such a `validate()` in other wrapper service and then in the end you consult that `errors` to be able to return whatever you want via its `hasErrors()` and `getAllErrors()`.

I have showed you some way in this answer: [Validator Spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575227/validator-spring-integration)